# Generate a data structure in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

i have Perl "config files" containing data structures like this:

```
'xyz' => {
    'solaris'  => [
                   "value1",
                   "valueN",
                  ],
    'linux'    => [
                   "valueX",
                   "valueN",
                  ],
},
```

i call them doing a simple :

```
%config = do '/path/to/file.conf';
```

now, i would like to "generate" config files like this (construct a data structure "structure" directly and print it in a config file).
i can fill the hash of hashes (of arrays or anything) in a normal way, but how do i dump it afterwards in a config file ?

is there a clean & easy way of doing it ?
instead of having to do dirty things like :

```
print $FH "'xyz' => {\n";
print $FH "   'solaris'  => [\n";
```

etc.

i "guess" Data::Dumper could do that..

thanks!

Comment: Data::Dumper and Data::Dump are meant for this.

Comment: thanks will try that

Comment: it almost work by doing print $FH Dumper ( \%HoH ); but it adds a $VAR1 = { at the top which is annoying, is there a way to get rid of it ?

Comment: (i mean i just need the hash contents, not the name of it), trying a couple of options atm

Comment: At the risk of "starting something", you might look at some of the JSON modules if it's going to interact with something other than perl.  I'm not a big JSON fan, but I ran into it when interacting with perl, javascript and java in the same project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
```

See [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper).

> $Data::Dumper::Terse or $OBJ->Terse([NEWVAL])
>
> When set, Data::Dumper will emit single, non-self-referential values as atoms/terms rather than statements. This means that the `$VAR`n names will be avoided where possible, but be advised that such output may not always be parseable by `eval`.

**Update (to address the comment below):**

Data::Dumper will add the correct punctuation in order for you to get back exactly what you give it. If you give it a hash reference, then you will get a string that starts and ends with curly braces.

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -E'$Data::Dumper::Terse=1; say Dumper { foo => { bar => "baz" }}'
{
  'foo' => {
             'bar' => 'baz'
           }
}
```

If you give it an array reference, then you will get back a string that starts and ends with square brackets.

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -E'$Data::Dumper::Terse=1; say Dumper [ foo => { bar => "baz" }]'
[
  'foo',
  {
    'bar' => 'baz'
  }
]
```

If, for some reason, you want neither of those, then give it a list of values.

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -E'$Data::Dumper::Terse=1; say Dumper ( foo => { bar => "baz" })'
'foo'
{
  'bar' => 'baz'
}
```

If you have a hash reference and you don't want the surrounding braces (which seems like a strange requirement, to be honest) then dereference the reference before passing it to `Dumper()`. That will convert the hash reference to a hash and the hash will be "unrolled" to a list by being passed to a function.

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -E'$Data::Dumper::Terse=1; $ref = { foo => { bar => "baz" }}; say Dumper %$ref'
'foo'
{
  'bar' => 'baz'
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! almost working like a charm except that it adds two braces at the top and the end of the file (arround the hash), will check if i can get rid of them in any way and mark the question as resolved

Comment: Thank you very much, it perfectly makes sense